# Show success/error message on dropzone file upload

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.1, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone file upload, when I return success / error from controller, how do I show it on my view file..

**View file** ,

```
 <div class="box-body">
    @if ( $errors->count() > 0 )
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        {{ $message = 'Please select csv file only.' }}
    </div>
    @endif

{!! Form::open([ 'url' => 'admin/reports','class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'reportfile' ]) !!}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 style="text-align : center">Select File</h3>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Report</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $validator = Validator::make(
                        [
                    'file' => $file,
                    'extension' => strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
                        ], [
                    'file' => 'required',
                    'extension' => 'required|in:csv',
                        ]
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return Response::json('error', 400);

        }
```

**JS Code**

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {

    Dropzone.options.reportfile = {
        paramName: "file", 
        maxFilesize: 2,
        error: function (file, response) {
            alert('hiii')
        },
        init: function () {
            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                alert("Added file.");
            });
        },
        accept: function (file, done) {
            alert('hi')
            if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
                done("Naha, you don't.");
            }

        }

    };
};
</script>
```

Not even alert is working...any help is much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Does this shows any error in your console ?

Comment: Yes its showing "error" string on console response tab.Also showing "400 Bad Request" in console as I'm returning 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: add ; in `alert('hi');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen the events, and trigger whether it is success or not

```
Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
  init: function() {
    this.on('success', function( file, resp ){
       alert("Success");
    });
  },
  ...
};
```

Note : You can have the other breakpoints as suggested [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/file-upload-form-express-dropzone-js/)

Comment: is uploadWidget id or name of form??

Comment: It depends on initiating it. You can also have like `var uploader = new Dropzone(‘#upload-widget’, options);` if you trying to have the `id` of the form

Comment: How to listen to 400 error from serverside response to dropzone event. I used error event but its not working.

Comment: I googled and found the error event for it. Thank you. We can refere to dropzonejs official site